# How to use difxapi.dll in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I need to use difxapi.dll from my Delphi project (Pascal). I tried to import it as a type library in Delphi, but Delphi gave me an error with a long backtrace.

Maybe i am doing something wrong? How should i correctly add this lib to my Delphi project so i can use it? It's Delphi XE2 if it matters.

Comment: What is the actual error that Delphi is reporting?

Comment: Isn't difxapi.dll a "standard" DLL and not an Active X DLL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DIFxAPI` is a standard 32-bit dynamic link library (DLL), not an ActiveX library. There is no `type library` to import for a normal DLL.

To use DIFxAPI.DLL in your application, you need to translate the `DIFxAPI.h` file to Delphi, and then call those imported procedures from your Delphi application. (You'll want to either import the `W` versions of the API functions, or use `PAnsiChar` instead of `PChar` in your imported functions, as XE2 uses Unicode.)

You can find more information on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) pages in [Linking an Installation Application to DIFxAPI.DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548642%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. This was my suspicion too.

Comment: @user This is the answer. Is suggest that you accept it.